# Recipe asks for "15 cardamom pods, crushed". Do I keep the shells?

Tags: spices, grinding

do I just crush the pods in a pestle and keep the pods in or do I remove the seeds from the pods and then crush them?

this is for a flavouring for grilled chicken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get ground seeds I usually pound the whole pods once or twice in a mortar. The seeds should separate from the husk easily then. Remove the entire pod from the mortar, and grind the seeds.

Is this recipe for a marinade? You might get away with just crushing the pods, not separating the husk and seeds.

Comment: Yep for a marinade! So I'll keep the husks then. Thanks

Comment: @George - the recipe might want husks for a reason, if they're asking for whole pods crushed instead of just the seeds (whole or ground).

Comment: Throwing the whole crushed pod in (and removing it before serving, or serving the dish with a warning :) ) seems typical of south asian recipes ... but then, given i've seen "may you bite into an elaichi!" as a humorous curse, I guess this is not unanimous :)

Comment: The husks don't add anything if you've cracked them open, so whatever the recipe means you might as well leave then out.

Comment: Oh, they do - if you only slighty crack them open, they make it more convenient to get the seeds out of anything that you want infused!